# Getting text() of object up the DOM tree? - Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

I have this markup (removed all unneccesary info)

```
<li>
<a></a>
<strong class="listingAmount">1</strong> 
<strong class="listingPrice">10</strong> 
<form class="marketListing">
<select>
</select>
<input />
</form>
</li>
```

I am trying to get the values of `.listingAmount` and `.listingPrice` on a `change event` of the select box in jquery. I have tried numerous methods involving `.parent()`, `.prev()`, `.closest()` and alot of others and just can't seem to get it!

My jquery so far,

```
$('.marketListing select').change(function() {
    var price = $(this).parent().prev('.listingPrice').text();
    var amount = $(this).parent().prev('listingAmount').text();
    alert(price);
    alert(amount);
});
```

How can I get the values I want that are previous to the `select`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `prevAll` not `prev`.  The `prev` function will only search the immediate previous node while `prevAll` will search all previous nodes.  Here's a functioning fiddle

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UasBq/

```
$('.marketListing select').change(function() {
    var price = $(this).parent().prevAll('.listingPrice').text();
    var amount = $(this).parent().prevAll('.listingAmount').text();
    alert(price);
    alert(amount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably put a class on the `<li>` so that I'd have a known and easy to find container, then you go up to the `<li>` and come back down to find what you're interested in:

```
<ul>
    <li class="container">
        <!-- ... -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then a simple combination of [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) gets you want you want:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var $cont  = $(this).closest('.container');
    var amount = $cont.find('.listingAmount').text();
    var price  = $cont.find('.listingPrice').text();
    // ...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kAejF/

The advantage of this over trying to use `prev` and `prevAll` is that your jQuery is very loosely coupled with your HTML: you only need simple containment, the nesting and internal structure is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close:

```
$('.marketListing select').change(function() {
  var li = $(this).closest('li');

  var price = $('.listingPrice', li).text();
  var amount = $('.listingAmount', li).text();
  alert(price);
  alert(amount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do something like:

```
$('.marketListing select').change(function() {
  var price = $(this).parents('form').prevAll('.listingPrice:first').text();
  var amount = $(this).parents('form').prevAll('.listingAmount:first').text();
  ...
  ...
});
```

This will, from the select, find the first parent FORM element. Then it will scan all its previous siblings and find the first .listingPrice (and .listingAmount).

I use :first in case there is more than one .listingPrice class that is a sibling to the form. I didn't add :first to the parents('form') because if you had nested form elements, you have bigger problems :P